# Unauthorized tokens (Response of 401) on accessTokens in Amplify

Tags: typescript, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm having problems with accessTokens recieved from cognitoUser.getSession. All the tokens are recieved properly and none of them are expired. Whenever I make a request to the backend, I get a 401 Unauthorized response. The tokens are fetched when I try to log in with google as a provider. Am I fetching the tokens properly or is it an error in the backend department? I'm pretty sure my configuration for the aws is correct.

This is what I've tried so far:

Login/page.tsx:

```
'use client'

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Hub } from "aws-amplify/utils";
import { signInWithRedirect, signOut, getCurrentUser, decodeJWT } from "aws-amplify/auth";
import { AuthUser } from "aws-amplify/auth";
import { CognitoUserPool, CognitoUser, CognitoUserSession } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

export async function currentSession() {
  
  const isTokenExpired = (token: string | undefined): boolean => {
    if (!token) return true;
  
    const decodedToken = decodeJWT(token);
    const expiration = decodedToken?.payload?.exp ?? 0;
    const currentTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  
    return expiration < currentTimestamp;
  };
  try {
    let poolData = { 
      UserPoolId : 'user_pool_id_placeholder',
      ClientId : "client_id_placeholder",
    };
    const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    const userData = {
        Username : (await getCurrentUser()).username,
        Pool : userPool
    };
    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData)
  
    cognitoUser.getSession(async (err: Error | null, session: CognitoUserSession | null) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error getting session:', err);
        return;
      }
      console.log("getSession is called");
      console.log("Cognito User Session:", session);
      // Access the JWT tokens
      const idToken = session?.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
      const accessToken = session?.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
      const refreshToken = session?.getRefreshToken()?.getToken();
     
      console.log('ID Token:', idToken);
      console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
      console.log('Refresh Token:', refreshToken);

      const decodedAccessToken = decodeJWT(accessToken ? accessToken?.toString(): "");
      console.log('Access Token Decoded:', decodedAccessToken);

      const decodedIdToken = decodeJWT(idToken ? idToken?.toString(): "");
      console.log('Id Token Decoded:', decodedIdToken);



    })

    
   
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error in currentSession:", err);
  }

 }
 
export default function Login() {
  
  const [user, setUser] = useState<AuthUser | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<unknown>(null);
  const [customState, setCustomState] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload }) => {
      switch (payload.event) {
        case "signInWithRedirect":
          getUser();
          break;
        case "signInWithRedirect_failure":
          setError("An error has ocurred during the Oauth flow.");
          break;
        case "customOAuthState":
          setCustomState(payload.data);
          break;
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const getUser = async (): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
      setUser(currentUser);
;
    
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in getUser:", error);
      console.log("Not signed in");
    }
  };



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => signInWithRedirect()}>Open Hosted UI</button>
      <button onClick={() => signInWithRedirect({ provider: "Facebook" })}>
        Open Facebook
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => signInWithRedirect({ provider: "Google" })}>
        Open Google
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
      <div>{user?.username}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App/page.tsx:

```
'use client'
import type { WithAuthenticatorProps } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import './config/aws-config'
import { currentSession } from './login/page';
import { useEffect } from 'react';




export function App({ signOut, user }: WithAuthenticatorProps) {

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () =>  {
      await currentSession()
    };
  
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Username: {user?.username}</h1> <br />
      <h1>userId: {user?.userId}</h1>
      <h1>signInDetailsAuthFlowType: {user?.signInDetails?.authFlowType} </h1>
      <h1>signInDetailsLoginId: {user?.signInDetails?.loginId} </h1>
      <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

I also checked the issuer for the tokens I get from the cognito.getSession and I figured the tokens are issued by cognito, and not by google.

Any help would be appreciated